# ByteCount on Function

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, associations, memory, data-structures

I was comparing RAM and CPU efficiency for List, Rule, Association, Function. The following code

```
n=10^6; 
tbl=Table[2i,{i,n}];                    ByteCount[tbl]
rls=Table[2i->i,{i,n}];                 ByteCount[rls]
asc=Association@Table[2i->i,{i,n}];     ByteCount[asc]
Do[fnc[2i]=i,{i,n}];                    ByteCount[fnc]
AbsoluteTiming[Position[tbl,2n][[1,1]]]
AbsoluteTiming[2n/.rls]
AbsoluteTiming[asc[2n]]
AbsoluteTiming[fnc[2n]]
```

gave the following results:

> 8000144
>
> 96000080
>
> 128382000
>
> 0
>
> {0.142235, 1000000}
>
> {0.805691, 1000000}
>
> {0.00001, 1000000}
>
> {4.*10^-6, 1000000}

Thus Function is the fastest, but how do I get its real memory requirement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using positive integer labels with rather high density in their range you should also try a classical array as lookup table. A further variant that works well when the keys are integers or lists of integers with fixed length is by using a BSP tree like with `Nearest`:

```
n = 10^6;
tbl = Table[2 i, {i, n}]; ByteCount[tbl]
rls = Table[2 i -> i, {i, n}]; ByteCount[rls]
rls2 = Dispatch[rls]; ByteCount[rls2]
asc = AssociationThread[Range[2, 2 n, 2], Range[n]]; ByteCount[asc]
ClearAll[fnc];
Do[fnc[2 i] = i, {i, n}]; ByteCount[DownValues[fnc]]
lookuptable = ConstantArray[0, 2 n];
lookuptable[[2 ;; ;; 2]] = Range[1, n]; ByteCount[lookuptable]
nf = Nearest[Range[2, 2 n, 2] -> Automatic];values = Range[n];ByteCount[nf] + ByteCount[values]
```

> 8000144
>
> 96000080
>
> 126473520
>
> 126473432
>
> 192000080
>
> 16000144
>
> 16000488

```
a = 2 RandomInteger[{1, n}, 100000];
RepeatedTiming[r2 = a /. rls2][[1]]
RepeatedTiming[r3a = asc /@ a][[1]]
RepeatedTiming[r3b = Lookup[asc, a]][[1]]
RepeatedTiming[r4 = fnc /@ a][[1]]
RepeatedTiming[r5 = lookuptable[[a]]][[1]]
RepeatedTiming[r6 = values[[Flatten[nf[a, 1]]]]][[1]]
r2 = r3a == r3b == r4 == r5 == r6
```

> 0.907
>
> 0.8451
>
> 0.614
>
> 1.0
>
> 0.011
>
> 0.11
>
> True

Also notice that these methods behave very differently to each other when looking up invalid keys.

Comment: What a nice overview of methods.

Comment: Thanks! When you say that, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

In your example the value of the argument is a part of the definition. Value of `fnc[2 i]`, where `i` is a symbol, is not defined in your MWE.

```
Total@Table[ByteCount[fnc[2 i]], {i, n}]
```

> 16 000 000

(Edit: note, that my solution only gives only the size of the right hand side and probably underestimates the real memory cost. See [the other solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180645/2036).)

Note also, that your timing measurement lead to misleading results as you apply it to so simple operations. Compare to

```
n2 = 10;
AbsoluteTiming[Position[tbl, #] & /@ (2 RandomInteger[n, n2])] // First
AbsoluteTiming[Replace[rls] /@ (2 RandomInteger[n, n2]);] // First
```

> ```
> 2.19423    
> 1.8028
> ```

Both of these approaches are very slow, as they require going through the whole list to fine the element.

These are much much faster:

```
n2 = 100000;
AbsoluteTiming[fnc /@ (2 RandomInteger[n, n2]);] // First
AbsoluteTiming[asc /@ (2 RandomInteger[n, n2]);] // First
AbsoluteTiming[Lookup[asc, 2 RandomInteger[n, n2]];] // First

> 0.267781
> 0.226777
> 0.171752
```

I think it is misleading to call `fnc[i]` a function, as a function usually is evaluated runtime. In your MWE you save a precomputed value. This technique is referred to as [*memoization*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/memoization).

When you wonder which one you should use, I would always use what makes sense semantically, because the engineers behind the kernel and native commands have but a lot of effort into finding a balance between all the features one usually needs from a `List`, `Rules`, `Associations` and `Symbols`. `Associations` and `Symbols` are the ones, which require fast random access.

Comment: Hmm, this is very low RAM usage, comparable to Table, yet faster than all of them. Why wouldn't one use Function instead of Table or Association?

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Your problem is that `foo /@ 2 RandomInteger[n, n2]` is parsed as `(foo /@ 2) RandomInteger[n, n2]`.

Comment: @CarlWoll oh lord. how stupid.

Comment: I fixed it now and adjusted my conclusions. I did think it had to be impossible for the lookup from `List` to be that fast. Now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

[`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html) should get close to the actual value I believe.

```
ByteCount[DownValues[fnc]]
```

> ```
> 192000080
> ```

You could also use MaxMemoryUsed during the construction:

```
ClearAll[fnc]

MaxMemoryUsed[Do[fnc[2 i] = i, {i, 10^6}];]
```

> ```
> 168327840
> ```

Comment: `DownValues` returns way more, than only the right hand side. Is it a fair comparison? I guess all memory structures should be compared by `DownValues` then.

Comment: @Johu I think it's a good first order approximation at least.  I did provide a second method that I presume is more accurate.